# Observing change of a property made within a "brother" polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, observers

I have a parent element with 2 child's:

```
<dom-module id="app-frontend">
<app-frontend-header logoff="{{_logoff}}" current-page="[[_page]]"></app-frontend-header>
  <app-frontend-page-profile id="profilepage"
                    logoff="{{_logoff}}" name="profile">
                </app-frontend-page-profile>

      Polymer({
     is: 'app-frontend',

        properties: {
           _logoff: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false, 
                notify:true,
            }, 
   });
</dom-module>
```

I'm changing the value of logoff (from false to true) inside header element and I'm trying to run a function in profile element by using an observer

```
triggerLogoff: function(logoff) {
        debugger;
             console.log("header " + logoff);
     },

     observers: [
        'triggerLogoff(logoff)'
     ]
```

It doesn't want to run (except at the beginning). I can see the property change is observed in the parent element using a similar observer:

```
      triggerLogoff: function(_logoff) {
         if (_logoff==true) {
              console.log("changed ");
            }
        },
      observers: [
            'triggerLogoff(_logoff)'
        ]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: within the header element, have you set logoff property notify true? Also, you don't have to set notify true in your parent element.

Comment: Yes, in the header the notify is true. I also removed the notify on the parent.I tried all kind of combinations... the logoff property in the profile element is not initialized with the value of parent _logoff property and any subsequent change is not reflected to that child... only to the header one. So it looks like something is "preventing" this element to behave "normally"... what could it be?

Comment: Problem solved: there was an extra "layer" in between, meaning an extra child element between parent and profile. The name on these 2 elements was almost similar so it tricked me. (as these were coming from a template application).